# Can anyone help figure out why my HTML email looks different in IE/Chrome?

Tags: html, css, email

I've been designing an HTML e-mail template, and have a few bugs that I haven't been able to solve. Here's my page:

1. When I view the page in IE, the right most column has a really large right margin that I can't seem to get rid of. I have tried setting margin-right: 0px.
2. When viewed in Chrome, the FB badge doesn't stay in the bottom right fully. Rather, it slightly floats above. CSS floats are not an option in HTML emails.

Any ideas? I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Some notes: yes - nested tables. For those unaware, in order to ensure the html/css formatting isn't stripped out, tables are a necessity for HTML emails. I originally coded this with pure CSS, but to no avail (doesnt render across major clients).

Comment: I don't see the FB badge positioning issue. It looks the same in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Answer (score 0):

1. you've set your `td` width to 100px..
2. make a new column and set the td to `valign="bottom"` and `align="right"`

Comment: 1. Hmm yeah, I was playing around with spacing. Set the left column to a set width and left column to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your problem with IE, your web-page does not have a DOCTYPE. As a result, quirks mode is activated. In quirks mode, the page is rendered differently. To disable quirks mode, add a DOCTYPE at the top of your web-page:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: I've been told that doctypes get stripped by email clients. I included a doctype just now anyways

Comment: Those e-mail clients are web-applications (Gmail, Hotmail, ...), or?

Comment: Hmm I heard it from a tutorial vid, assuming it was all clients, web-based or not. A quick google search found this: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3317/correct-doctype-to-use-in-html-email/ 

So I guess I'll just go with that doctype haha